# How Can I Include a Typescript Generated js.map File as a WebResource in a Web Control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, typescript

I have a JavaScript source file, generated by TypeScript, which I include in an ASP.net web control using the WebResource attribute.   The generated JavaScript file includes a reference to the generated js.map file.   If the map file was included as a WebResource in the web control, the resource URL is going to be some compiler generated URL.   While I could find out what that is, and attempt to modify the JS file manually, it will get overwritten on any build.

Is there a better solution for this use case?

Comment: Why would you want to have this? The map file is only for debugging the typescript. If you publish your control, you don't want to expose your source files anyways right? And for debugging your own control you could find another solution, e.g. link to your test website and have all map files somewhere in one folder

Comment: @Ela - What you are suggesting is not a user friendly solution for the distribution of a shared control that may be used in different environments by different developers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access the resources via

```
var file = <AppNameSpace>.Properties.Resources.<jsfilename>
```

or load it as stream

```
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("<fullname>");
```

In both cases you should be able to actually modify it (not sure).
If this is not possible, you would have to write a small service which returns the script, read it from your resource, modify it and then return it back...

Comment: I think you are right.  Perhaps the script can be modified as it streams out, to grab the js.map file name, then get the URL to that resource by name (not sure of the method call that would do this yet but if you can get it by name as you mention above you would think that you could get its URL as well), then replace the js.map reference with the URL for the embedded js.map resource.  Cacheing would come into play here as well. +1 for now for thinking it through.  Check mark later if it turns out this is the answer.